# Advise: Proper method to store schedule in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Disclaimer: I haven't gotten to the database class yet at my university, so please excuse me if I sound ignorant :) I have searched around online and I have found some related information, but nothing that looked like it would work for this specific type of situation.

I have a MySQL database which stores user information.  I already have columns for name, id, different contact info, etc.

My software has an alerting functionality which allows each user to create a custom alert scheme.  You can check a box to receive alerts 5m, 15m, 1hr, 2hr, 1d, 2d before the event.  There are identical alert schemes available for email and text message alerts, which means that I will need to store 12-20 boolean values per user.

It seems like it would be ugly to do this with 20 columns of TINYINTs for each user, so I've been using a shorthand notation (with CSVs) in a string column.  I am sure there is a better way of doing things.

Thank you in advance for your valuable assistance!

Comment: Can we see your shorthand notation please?

Comment: I had one column for SMS alerts, and one column for email alerts.  If a user selected 1hr, 2hr, 6hr, 12hr, 1d, 2d alerts, the program would make a string that looks like "1,2,6,12,24,48" and store that.  I have a feeling that this is terribly inefficient to search: select mailTimes from [concerned users], split to CSV (back in C# app) then remove users from alerting list who don't have matching alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use many-to-many relation:

```
CREATE TABLE alerts (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
CREATE TABLE alerts_users (alert_id INT, user_id INT);
INSERT INTO alerts (name) values ('5m'), ('15m'), ('1hr'), ('2hr'), ('1d'), ('2d');
```

Add alert `15m` to user with `id = 1`:

```
INSERT INTO alerts_users VALUES ((SELECT id FROM alerts WHERE name = '15m'), 1);
```

Get all alerts of user with `id = 1`:

```
SELECT name FROM alerts a INNER JOIN alerts_users ON a.id = alert_id WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like this makes sense, but I will have to do some more research on how to implement it with my existing structure.